# Display html code on condition in jsp

Tags: jsp

I want to append html tags to jsp page when DB result is null. I used `out.write()` and `out.print()` but these functions has any result.

This my jsp code:

```
<div id="result">
            <label>Trend:</label> <select class="form-control"
                disabled="disabled" style="width: 200px;"><option><%=session.getAttribute("building").toString()%></option></select>
            <label>Year: </label>
            <%
                String tab = null, courseid = null;
               int cnt=0;
                String building = session.getAttribute("building").toString();
                //System.out.println("\n" + building);
                {
                    ResultSet rs = new report2().year_in_dept(building);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        cnt++;
                    }

                }
                ResultSet rs = new report2().year_in_dept(building);
            %>
            <br />

            <div style="width: 200px;">
                <select id="yearlist" class="form-control">
                    <%
                        String id = null;
                        if (cnt>0) {
                            while (rs.next()) {
                    %>
                    <option style="color: red;" value="<%=rs.getString("year")%>">
                        <%
                            System.out.println(rs.getString("year"));
                                    out.println(rs.getString("year"));
                        %>
                    </option>

                    <%
                        }
                        }
                        else{
                            out.print("<div class=\"col-md-7 col-md-offset-3\" id=\"error\" style=\"margin-top:-600px;\">"
                                    + "<div id=\"alertbar\" class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissible\" role=\"alert\">"
                                    + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">"
                                    + "<span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span><span class=\"sr-only\">Close</span>"
                                    + "</button>"
                                    + "<strong>Warning!</strong> In your selected semester and year not exist."
                                    + "</div>"
                                    + "</div>");
                            System.out.print("kkk");
                        }
                    %>
                </select> <label>Semester:</label> <select class="form-control"
                    style="width: 200px;" id="semester">
                    <option style="color: red;" value="Fall">Fall</option>
                    <option style="color: red;" value="Spring">Spring</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                id="showresult" value="Show Result">
            <div id="container"
                style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"
                data-highcharts-chart="0"></div>
        </div>
```

I want this result print in my determined position,and now I don't know what do to do.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Isn't the code you wrote servlet code instead of JSP code or is it called through scriptlet in the JSP? Can you give more context on the posted code?

Comment: System.out will print to your console, not within the JSP output, as you seem to expect. Better go ahead using <%= =>, this should work.

Comment: I know,but my purpose is else section!